# Making a State variable of ToolbarContent SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, state, toolbar

I am working on a SwiftUI project, and I am trying to have multiple different `Toolbar` versions in my app. When one button is pressed, they ideally should change. So, I have defined a few different Toolbars using this definition (the actual code in the toolbars is not important):

```
@ToolbarContentBuilder fileprivate var ______: some ToolbarContent {
    ToolbarItem(...)
    ToolbarItem(...)
}
```

My next step is to create a `@State` variable that holds the currently selected toolbar. I tried to do this:

```
@State var navBarView: some ToolbarContent = _________
```

However, this gave the error:

```
Result builder attribute 'ToolbarContentBuilder' can only be applied to a property if it defines a getter
```

Does anyone know how to complete this goal or get around this error? Thanks!

Comment: Don't make a `State` out of a `ToolbarContent`. Use an enum or something like that to represent the state of the toolbar.

Comment: @Sweeper How would I use the enum to do this? I can't assign a raw value of the `ToolbarContent` to the enum

Comment: Instead of using `rawValue`, just declare a computed property in the enum that returns the appropriate `ToolbarContent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `ToolbarContent` as a `@State`, in the same way that you should have a `View` as a `@State`.

Create an enum that encodes the many toolbars that you have, e.g.

```
enum ToolbarState {
    case one, two
    
    @ToolbarContentBuilder
    var content: some ToolbarContent {
        switch self {
        case .one:
            ToolbarItem {
                Button("Foo1") {
                    
                }
            }
            ToolbarItem {
                Button("Foo2") {
                    
                }
            }
        case .two:
            ToolbarItem {
                Button("Bar") {
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Use this as the state:

```
@State var toolbarState = ToolbarState.one

var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
        Button("Change State") {
            toolbarState = .two
        }.toolbar {
            toolbarState.content
        }
    }
}
```